# Need help on SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

### I have 2 tables as below:

---

```
select 1 as id,
'A' as place 
into #places
UNION
select 2 as id,
'B' as place 
UNION
select 3 as id,
'C' as place
UNION
select 4 as id,
'D' as place
```

---

```
select 'x' as name,
2 as start,
3 as endd 
into #travel
UNION
select 'y' as name,
4 as start,
1 as endd
UNION
select 'z' as name,
1 as start,
3 as endd

select * from #places
select * from #travel
```

### ------------------------------

Now I want to get name/start place/end place using joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select #travel.*, pstart.place as start, pend.place as end
from #travel inner join #places as pstart on pstart.id = #travel.start
inner join #places as pend on pend.id = #travel.end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 t.name,
 p1.place as start_place,
 p2.place as end_place
FROM
 travel t
 JOIN places p1 on t.start = p1.id
 JOIN places p2 on t.endd = p2.id
```